# hazelcast query performance with predicate aggregation

Tags: java, performance, hazelcast, predicate

is there any difference in term of performances between two queries executed with a predicate built like that:

```
Predicates.and(pred1, Predicates.and(pred2, pred3))
```

or like that:

```
Predicates.and(pred1, pred2, pred3)
```

(also consider that the list of predicates may be longer than 3)

Comment: First one creates 2 Predicates while second one creates only one. Second is faster and cheaper (memory wise and what follows it) in creation, but for the query after, no impact.

Comment: well, pred1 pred2 and pred3 are all predicates...
So yes the first example creates one more predicate for each predicate over the third, but is this influencing the performances of the query?

Comment: No. Because predicate is fully calculated before being run on data store level.

Comment: thanks for the response @AliBenZarrouk . Do you have any link that supports what you are saying? 
I would like to deepen the topic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

First one creates 2 Predicates while second one creates only one. Second is faster and cheaper (memory wise and what follows it) in creation, but for the query after, no impact.